# Customize labels on a color key using base R

Tags: r, plot, r-sf, color-palette

Consider this plot, which shows values ranging from `0.042` to `0.241`:

```
library(sf)
demo(nc, ask=FALSE, echo=FALSE)
brks <- seq(0, 0.2, by=0.05)
plot(nc["AREA"], key.pos=1, breaks=brks, at=brks)
```

[image]

However, let's say I need to customize the color key labels. I want add one "segment" to it in order to include values higher than 0.2.

For example:

```
brks2 <- c(seq(0, 0.2, by=0.05), 1)
plot(nc["AREA"], key.pos=1, breaks = brks2, at=brks2)
```

[image]

but the color key, rather than getting "stretched" from 0.2 to 1, should have just one more segment, with the label `>0.2` or similar.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

We could add `.25` to the breaks, but I didn't find an option in `sf:::plot.sf` to create custom labels, so last label would be `0.25`. Maybe you could set `at=2` (to print the labels outside the window) and build a custom `axis` and labels using `mtext`, but this becomes very cumbersome and inaccurate.

It might, thus, be better to use `nbreaks=`. You could also play around with `breaks=`, where `"pretty"` is default and other options are `"fixed", "sd", "equal", "pretty", "quantile", "kmeans", "hclust", "bclust",  "fisher", "jenks", "dpih", "headtails"`, see `?sf:::plot.sf`.

```
sf:::plot.sf(nc["AREA"], key.pos=1, breaks="pretty", nbreaks=5)
```

[image]

I think it's reasonable to [address the author](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/) with a feature request, or maybe someone else is able to hack `sf:::plot.sf`.